# Spring Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

Just wondering what is the correct way to inject a map in my Application.java file to be used in services in other classes using the Spring Java Config approach

If i setup 1 bean like this

```
@Bean(name = "databaseScheduler")
public SchedulerFactoryBean databaseScheduler() {
...
...
}
```

And reference if later like this then everything works as expected

```
@Inject
private SchedulerFactoryBean databaseScheduler;
```

But when  I try and setup a map of SchedulerFactoryBeans as follows

```
   @Bean(name = "databaseSchedulersMap")
public Map<Integer, SchedulerFactoryBean> databaseSchedulersMap() { 
....
....
}
```

And inject it later like so

```
@Resource
private Map<Integer, SchedulerFactoryBean> databaseSchedulersMap;
```

It doesnt work and properties on the bean are missing or null

Im setting up the SchedulerFactoryBean in the exact same manner as the single bean instance but its proving really difficult to get this going

Any help on this is greatly appreciated

Comment: did you tried with @Resource(name="databaseSchedulersMap") ?

Comment: I did yes. No joy unfortunately. The map is loaded with the correct number of beans in it. But the properties of the bean are not set

Comment: are you sure that in the databaseSchedulersMap properties are set? YOu didn't posted the method body, so I have to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies @Ma Kro

I tried your suggestion again with the `@Resource(name="databaseSchedulersMap")` and it worked

I must have had a typo in it the first time or something
Sorry about that